# How to remove all pixels that aren't connected to at least 10 another pixels in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to remove all pixels that aren't connected to at least 10 other pixels?
I want this

[image]

to look something like

[image: this].

Comment: Try using the "closing" operation of Mathematical Morphology, which removes small, isolated dark artifacts in an image.   Look at openCV for examples.

Comment: Please refactor your question .. follow the guide how to post..

Comment: didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [erosion](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html) and [dilation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation.html) to remove the grain works very well for this particular image

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage


img = np.dot(plt.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypBGu.png')[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

img = 1 - (img > .6)
img = ndimage.binary_erosion(img, structure=np.ones((2,2))).astype(int)
img = ndimage.binary_dilation(img, structure=np.ones((3,3))).astype(int)

labeled_array, num_features = ndimage.label(img)
label, counts = np.unique(labeled_array, return_counts=True)
labeled_array[np.isin(labeled_array, label[counts < 200])] = 0
```

This gives an array with every character's island pixels labeled

```
plt.imshow(labeled_array, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off');
```

Output

[image: result]

Comment: Saving the degrained image with `matplotlib`: `plt.imsave('filename.png', labeled_array)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that can be done with some KNN manipulation, but i suggest [erosion and dilation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/erosion-dilation-images-using-opencv-python/) to get rid of the noisy dots, using openCV for example.